# MVC partial view controller method not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call a controller method which returns a partial view. However the view returns with a null reference due to it being called without the controller.

How would I do it if I want to call the partial view throu the controller method.

So far my code looks like this:

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<div class="container" id="menu">
     @Html.Partial("~/Views/Category/_Menu.cshtml")
</div>
```

**CategoryController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Menu()
    {
        var model = new CategoryModel()
        {
            categories = new SortedDictionary<int, List<CategoryDTO>>()
        };

        model.categories[0] = new List<CategoryDTO>();
        model.categories[0].Add(new CategoryDTO()
        {
            id = 1,
            name = "Nålebinding"
        });
        model.categories[0].Add(new CategoryDTO()
        {
            id = 2,
            name = "Strik"
        });
        model.categories[0].Add(new CategoryDTO()
        {
            id = 3,
            name = "Hækling"
        });

        model.categories[1] = new List<CategoryDTO>();
        model.categories[1].Add(new CategoryDTO()
        {
            id = 4,
            name = "Sokker"
        });
        model.categories[1].Add(new CategoryDTO()
        {
            id = 5,
            name = "Vanter"
        });

        model.categories[2] = new List<CategoryDTO>();
        model.categories[2].Add(new CategoryDTO()
        {
            id = 6,
            name = "Sokker"
        });

        return PartialView("_Menu", model);
    }
```

**_Menu.cshtml**

```
@model GUI.Models.CategoryModel
@using DTO;

@helper subCategories(SortedDictionary<int, List<CategoryDTO>> list, int parent)
{
<ul>
    @foreach(var e in list[parent])
    {
        <li>
            @e.name

            @subCategories(list, e.id)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
}

@subCategories(Model.categories, 0)
```

Comment: You could try @Html.Action("Menu", "YourController") in place of the @Html.Partial.

Comment: `Html.Partial` loads the html view, however `Html.Action` calls the controller action and loads the response